# How does oracle's burden interact with the god-meddled curse?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, class-feature, curses, oracle

[Oracle's Burden](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Oracle%27s%20Burden) makes

> The target creature suffers all the hindrances and none of the benefits of your oracle’s curse class feature.

The God-Meddled [Curse](https://www.aonprd.com/OracleCurses.aspx) does

> Bizarre side effects occur whenever you are affected by a spell from a divine caster—for better or for worse. Once per round, when a creature casts a divine spell including you as a target, roll 1d20 and consult the table below. The effect resulting from this roll begins at the end of that enemy’s turn.

Basically you have a table of good and bad things that can happen to you when you are targeted by a divine spell, such as being blind for a round or getting your caster level increased for a round, with some of them being "grey", like being affected by reduce/enlarge person.

How would Oracle's Burden work when you have this Curse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of components to [God-Meddled Curse](https://www.aonprd.com/OracleCurses.aspx) that would be easy to rule on. The extra changes that occur at levels 5,10 and 15 would definitely not be applied to the target of the spell (because they are beneficial).

The rest is a little more up to interpretation. Personally, I would rule that the normal effect of God-meddled applies, but I would cancel any effect with a roll greater than 10. Most of the effects below 10 are detrimental, and Reduce is most often bad for the target, while Enlarge is most often a benefit. Alternatively, you could rule that you only roll 1d10 on the table, forcing all results to be in the bottom half of the results.

I could also see an argument for just applying any and all effects to the target, or not applying any of the effects to the target, since several of the results are not clearly a benefit or a hindrance, unlike with other Curses.